# Can't run apt update

Tags: dual-boot, apt, updates

I just installed Kali alongside Ubuntu 22.04 with no problem and can boot into both fine although I’ve not yet run an update in Kali (will do that soon).

When I tried to update Ubuntu I get this error

`Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00trustcdrom:1: Extra junk at end of file`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried to `cat` the file but it’s unreadable - I think encrypted as it’s just a few symbols.

I have tried looking online with little success and can’t seem to find any corresponding information.

Comment: Move the mentioned file to your $HOME.

Comment: Please format your post properly, so that everyone can read and understand it. One sentence one line will be a good choice.

Comment: @nobody thank you this worked, but why was it created or why did it need moved?

Comment: The file doesn't contain a lot on Ubuntu systems.`APT::Authentication::TrustCDROM "true";`

Comment: @nobody - I know it’s very brief, but your comment solved it - worth posting as an answer?

Comment: Strange I do not have this file. @Will I'm sure it is a dupplicate from something. But I'm too tired to search.